# How to have one legend for multiple subplots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, subplot

I have one figure with multiple subplots, and each subplot has the same number of lines (In my case it's 4 lines). How can I have one single legend (say, ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] ) on the side for all the subplots?

BTW, I plotted the subplot axes using

`fig, ax_list = plt.subplots(rows, cols)`

and then for each subplot

`ax_list[0][0].plot()`

[image]

Comment: If you know for sure that each `subplot` has 4 of the exact same lines, why don't you simply add labels for one `subplot`, and put a legend for that somewhere on the side (see e.g. this great answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4701285/3581217)?

Comment: Alternatively, using `fig.legend()` might be an option: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/figlegend_demo.html